# Intuition behind the central tendency for the driving speed in a non-frequency data

Tags: probability, statistics

A study on driving speed (km per hour) and fuel-efficiency (km per litre of petrol) for two-wheelers in a country has resulted in the following data:

Driving Speed :
$35~~
40~~
50~~
30~~
25~~
45~~
55~~
60~~
70~~
40~~
45~~
60$

Fuel Efficiency:
$50~~
50~~
50~~
55~~
45~~
50~~
40~~
35~~
30~~
55~~
45~~
30$

i. Compute measure of central tendency for the driving speed.

I can compute the harmonic mean as the central tendancy of the data since the data points are given in 'rates', How can we explain the philosophy behind the choice? Infact, the data given is not like a frequancy data.

In principle, is there logical connection between the typical tendancy with these two rows (Speed and Fuel Efficiency) in the data.